# Using Arrays to Compare and Share Data Between Multiple Workbooks and Worksheets

Tags: arrays, database, excel, vba, large-files

I have been writing this code for a few weeks now and it used to work, it took 2 hours to compile through the 49 worksheets I am comparing but for some reason it now just says not responding. I really want to try switching to use arrays so that if I can get it to work again it will go a lot faster. However even after reading a lot of posts about arrays I can't come up with a way to do it, besides knowing that I need to use a multidimensional array and have a varied row size. Can anyone give any advise? Thanks in advance!

More information, the code looks at what is in column e and if something else in column e matches it takes the values in columns t thru x and places them in that rows t thru x. It also colors the rows e if their t thru x are empty, or makes it white again if it finds it colored when it shouldn't be.

```
Sub FindPart_FullWorkbooks()

'If searching multiple worksheets & workbooks

Dim PartNumber As String
Dim Found1 As Integer
Dim Found2 As Boolean
Dim Found3 As Boolean
Dim Found4 As Boolean
Dim Found5 As Boolean
Dim Found6 As Boolean
Dim Found7 As Boolean
Dim Found8 As Boolean
Dim Found9 As Boolean
Dim Found10 As Boolean
Dim Found11 As Boolean
Dim Found12 As Boolean
Dim EOS As String
Dim EOSL As String
Dim EOL As String
Dim Replace As String
Dim AddInfo As String
Dim n As Long
Dim m As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim WS2 As Worksheet
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim WB2 As Workbook

For Each WB In Workbooks

For Each WS In WB.Worksheets

With WS
LastRow = .Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
End With

For m = 1 To LastRow

    PartNumber = WB.Sheets(WS.Name).Cells(m, 5).Value
    EOS = WB.Sheets(WS.Name).Cells(m, 20).Value
    EOSL = WB.Sheets(WS.Name).Cells(m, 21).Value
    EOL = WB.Sheets(WS.Name).Cells(m, 22).Value
    Replace = WB.Sheets(WS.Name).Cells(m, 23).Value
    AddInfo = WB.Sheets(WS.Name).Cells(m, 24).Value

    Found2 = IsEmpty(WB.Sheets(WS.Name).Cells(m, 5).Value)
    Found4 = IsEmpty(WB.Sheets(WS.Name).Cells(m, 20).Value)
    Found5 = IsEmpty(WB.Sheets(WS.Name).Cells(m, 21).Value)
    Found6 = IsEmpty(WB.Sheets(WS.Name).Cells(m, 22).Value)
    Found7 = IsEmpty(WB.Sheets(WS.Name).Cells(m, 23).Value)
    Found8 = IsEmpty(WB.Sheets(WS.Name).Cells(m, 24).Value)

    If Found2 = True Then
    GoTo NextIndex

        Else

        For Each WB2 In Workbooks
        For Each WS2 In WB2.Worksheets

            For n = 1 To LastRow

                Found1 = InStr(WB2.Sheets(WS2.Name).Cells(n, 5).Value, PartNumber)

                Found3 = IsEmpty(WB2.Sheets(WS2.Name).Cells(n, 20).Value)
                Found9 = IsEmpty(WB2.Sheets(WS2.Name).Cells(n, 21).Value)
                Found10 = IsEmpty(WB2.Sheets(WS2.Name).Cells(n, 22).Value)
                Found11 = IsEmpty(WB2.Sheets(WS2.Name).Cells(n, 23).Value)
                Found12 = IsEmpty(WB2.Sheets(WS2.Name).Cells(n, 24).Value)

                If Found3 = True And Found9 = True And Found10 = True And Found11 = True And Found12 = True Then

                    If Found1 = 1 Then
                        WB2.Sheets(WS2.Name).Cells(n, 20).Value = EOS
                        WB2.Sheets(WS2.Name).Cells(n, 21).Value = EOSL
                        WB2.Sheets(WS2.Name).Cells(n, 22).Value = EOL
                        WB2.Sheets(WS2.Name).Cells(n, 23).Value = Replace
                        WB2.Sheets(WS2.Name).Cells(n, 24).Value = AddInfo

                    End If
                End If
            Next n

        If Found4 = True And Found5 = True And Found6 = True And Found7 = True And Found8 = True Then

        WB.Sheets(WS.Name).Cells(m, 5).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 255)

        ElseIf WB.Sheets(WS.Name).Cells(m, 5).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 255) Then

        WB.Sheets(WS.Name).Cells(m, 5).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)

        End If

        'MsgBox (WB2.Name & " " & WS2.Name)

        Next WS2
        Next WB2

    End If
'MsgBox (m)
NextIndex:

 Next m
'MsgBox (WB.Name & " " & WS.Name)

 Next WS
 Next WB

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, but to clarify - does this work, just take lots of time? If so, you may want to ask this over at [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: It used to just take a lot of time but now it freezes excel and I am curious if anyone might know how to integrate arrays into it so that it might work better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer was meant for the [Code Review site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/169558/using-arrays-to-compare-and-share-data-between-multiple-workbooks-and-worksheets) but that question is on hold, so I'll provide it here

From a performance perspective you managed to code the worst-case scenario - maximum amount of work needed to accomplish the task. You probably did it just to get it working, and I'm up-voting the question because you made the right decision to ask for help

To illustrate consider we have 10 files, with 3 sheets each, and each sheet containing 1,000 rows (parts). What your algorithm does is loop through each file, and for each file loop through each file again (!), each sheet, and each row:

Result: 10 files * 3 sheets * 1,000 rows = 30,000 searches - interractions with the range

There are other issues as well:

- You overwrite all data several times, including overwriting valid data with empty strings
- Searching for a part number is not precise because of the InStr()
- Not to mention basic issues like a naming convention that makes the code very hard to read, and the GoTo statement which doesn't help either

The first step to improve performance is what you had in mind: convert to arrays, but even that can't cope very well with the massive amount of work because there is still a lot of file interaction (moving through them over and over again), so the next step is to optimize the logic

When converting to arrays, the main concept to understand is that an array has the same structure as the data on the sheet - you can imagine the sheet in memory using rows and columns, except that columns don't use letters, so if you copy the data to memory doing this: `dataArray = Sheet1.UsedRange`, you access it the same way:

- `Sheet1.UsedRange.Cells(1, 1)` = A1
- `dataArray(1, 1)` = A1

except arrays are exponentially faster. You don't need to worry about the 2 dimensions of the array, if that makes things complicated, because VBA generates the proper array in this simple assignment **`dataArray = Sheet1.UsedRange`**, where `dataArray` should be defined as a `Variant`

Then, the only extra step needed after all processing is completed is to copy the data back to the sheet with this statement **`Sheet1.UsedRange = dataArray`**

So the first version I made is the original (inefficient) logic, converted to arrays, just to demonstrate how it can be done

The second version is an improved algorithm that iterates over all files, only twice

1. Once to read all part numbers into a dictionary
2. 2nd time to update all part numbers (missing the details in columns T through X), in all files

Results with my data (3 files, with 3 sheets each, and each sheet containing 1,000 rows):

> ```
> - v1: Time: 4399.262 sec (1.22 hrs) - your version
> - v2: Time:  770.797 sec (12.8 min) - your version converted to arrays
> - v3: Time:    2.684 sec            - optimized logic (arrays + dictionary)
> ```

---

Version 2 (arrays):

```
Public Sub FindPart_FullWorkbooks3()    '-----------------------------------------------
    Const FR = 2    'First row, after header
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim ur1 As Variant, ur2 As Variant, info1 As String,info2 As String, updt As Boolean
    Dim lr1 As Long, lr2 As Long, lc1 As Long, lc2 As Long, samePart As Boolean
    Dim m(1 To 6), i As Byte, cel As Range, yColor As Long, nColor As Long
    Dim r1 As Long, c1 As Long, r2 As Long, c2 As Long, y As Range, n As Range

    yColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    nColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)

    m(1) = 5
    m(2) = 20
    m(3) = 21
    m(4) = 22
    m(5) = 23
    m(6) = 24

    For Each wb1 In Workbooks
        For Each ws1 In wb1.Worksheets
            ur1 = ws1.UsedRange
            lr1 = UBound(ur1, 1)    'last row
            lc1 = UBound(ur1, 2)    'last col
            If lc1 >= 24 Then
                For r1 = FR To lr1
                    If Len(ur1(r1, m(1))) > 0 Then
                      info1 = ur1(r1, m(2)) & ur1(r1, m(3)) & ur1(r1, m(4))
                      info1 = info1 & ur1(r1, m(5)) & ur1(r1, m(6))
                      Set cel = ws1.Cells(r1, m(1))
                      If Len(info1) > 0 Then
                        For Each wb2 In Workbooks
                          For Each ws2 In wb2.Worksheets
                            ur2 = ws2.UsedRange
                            lr2 = UBound(ur2, 1)
                            lc2 = UBound(ur2, 2)
                            If lc2 >= 24 Then
                              For r2 = FR To lr2
                                info2 = ur2(r2, m(2)) & ur2(r2, m(3)) & ur2(r2, m(4))
                                info2 = info2 & ur2(r2, m(5)) & ur2(r2, m(6))
                                samePart = InStr(ur2(r2, m(1)), ur1(r1, m(1))) = 1
                                If (samePart And Len(info2) = 0) Then
                                  For i = 1 To 6
                                      ur2(r2, m(i)) = ur1(r1, m(i))
                                  Next
                                  updt = True
                                End If
                              Next
                            End If
                            If updt Then
                              ws2.UsedRange = ur2
                              updt = False
                            End If
                          Next
                        Next
                        If y Is Nothing Then Set y = cel Else Set y = Union(y, cel)
                      Else
                        If n Is Nothing Then Set n = cel Else Set n = Union(n, cel)
                      End If
                    End If
                Next
                If Not y Is Nothing Then
                    If y.Interior.Color = nColor Then y.Interior.Color = yColor
                    Set y = Nothing
                End If
                If Not n Is Nothing Then
                    n.Interior.Color = nColor
                    Set n = Nothing
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

---

Version 3 (Arrays and Dictionary)

```
Public Function UpdateAllParts() As Long    '------------------------------------------
    Const FR = 2    'First row, after header
    Const DELIM = "<*>"
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, ur As Variant, i As Byte, iter As Long
    Dim lr As Long, lc As Long, m(1 To 6), inf As String, frst As Boolean
    Dim yColor As Long, nColor As Long, y As Range, n As Range, d As Dictionary
    Dim cel As Range, lenDelim As Long, vals As Variant, r As Long, c As Long

    yColor = RGB(255, 255, 255):    nColor = RGB(255, 0, 0):    Set d = New Dictionary
    m(1) = 5:   m(2) = 20:  m(3) = 21:  m(4) = 22:  m(5) = 23:  m(6) = 24

    lenDelim = Len(DELIM) * 4
    For iter = 1 To 2
      frst = iter = 1
      For Each wb In Workbooks
        For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
          ur = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1), ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))
          lr = UBound(ur, 1): lc = UBound(ur, 2)
          If lc >= 24 Then
            For r = FR To lr
              If Len(ur(r, m(1))) > 0 Then
                If frst Then Set cel = ws.Cells(r, m(1))
                inf = ur(r, m(2)) & DELIM & ur(r, m(3)) & DELIM & ur(r, m(4))
                inf = inf & DELIM & ur(r, m(5)) & DELIM & ur(r, m(6))
                If frst Then
                    If Len(inf) > lenDelim Then
                        d(ur(r, m(1))) = inf 'add all to dict
                        If cel.Interior.Color = nColor Then
                            If y Is Nothing Then Set y = cel Else Set y = Union(y, cel)
                        End If
                    Else
                        If n Is Nothing Then Set n = cel Else Set n = Union(n, cel)
                    End If
                Else
                  If Len(inf) = lenDelim Then
                    If d.Exists(ur(r, m(1))) Then
                      vals = Split(d(ur(r, m(1))), DELIM)
                      For i = 0 To 4
                        ur(r, m(i + 2)) = vals(i)
                      Next
                    End If
                  End If
                End If
              End If
            Next
            If frst Then
              If Not y Is Nothing Then
                If y.Interior.Color = nColor Then y.Interior.Color = yColor
                Set y = Nothing
              End If
              If Not n Is Nothing Then
                n.Interior.Color = nColor
                Set n = Nothing
              End If
            Else
              ws.Range(ws.Cells(1), ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)) = ur
            End If
          End If
        Next
      Next
    Next
    UpdateAllParts = d.Count
End Function
```

---

Test data:

Before - all files with missing data:

[image: Before]

---

After - all files, v1 (yours) - notice the records outlined in blue - invalid data

[image: After - v1]

---

After - all files, v2 - same issue as in v1, accentuated by the array implementation

[image: After - v2]

---

After - all files, v3

[image: After - v3]

---

Comment: Thank you! This is a much better way to go about the code and I hadn't even noticed that it was inputting incorrect data. I would like some clarification about the coloring system however because what the colors had originally done was highlight  part numbers which do not have anything in the rows that are being filled, . Or make white the part numbers if there is even one column of data in one of those 5 rows that are being filled but it does not do this. Thank you very much for spending the amount of time it took to come up with this code. @paulbica

Comment: I am new to coding so reading exactly what your code is doing only partially makes sense to me. I had to comment out "OpenAllFiles" and "CloseAllFiles" because it wanted those to be a Sub or Function and I don't have that as either of them. I'm not sure if they were important terms, I assume they were put in so that I could use the code across any open workbooks which is something I want to be able to do.

Comment: @paulbica ,I won't need to use the subs you did because I will keep the workbooks I am using and need open or close them manually as well.  As far as I can tell the code only changes the color of the box if it is the first time the part number is seen while I actually need it to change for every time that part number is used as it fills in the 5 spaces. Thank you for your help on this manner.

Comment: @FrenchP: I can't test the code with your data but I wanted to show you different approaches related to performance at high level, such as converting your initial code to use arrays and dictionaries. Try to adjust the code to your specific data and requirements to get the results you need. Let me know if you have any issues and if you can provide a test file so I can duplicate the behavior and fix the problems

Comment: @FrenchP - I made changes to v3. Please try t and let me know if you see any issues